# While Loop Through An Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, infinite-loop, global

Creating a block builder that loops through blocks pulled form database in order.

```
if( loop_blocks()) {
    while( loop_blocks()) {
        if( have_block('standard-content-block')) {
            echo 'standard-content-block';
        }

        elseif( have_block('executive-intro-block')) {
            echo 'executive intro block';
        }
    }
}
```

My function loop_blocks pulls the blocks from the database in order and set the array as a global variable:

```
function loop_blocks() {
        global $db;

        $page_id = get_page_id();
        $GLOBALS['loop_position'] = 0;
        $loop_position = $GLOBALS['loop_position'];

        $stm = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM page_blocks WHERE page_id = :id ORDER BY `block_order` ASC");
        $stm->execute(array(':id' => $page_id));
        $res = $stm->fetchAll();
        $GLOBALS['block_loop'] = $res;
        if(!$res) {
            return false;
        } elseif(!$GLOBALS['block_loop'][$loop_position]) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The function have_block gets the current loop position and determines whether the name as determined, exists in the array and increases the loop position:

```
function have_block($block_name) {
        $loop_position = $GLOBALS['loop_position'];

        if(!$GLOBALS['block_loop'][$loop_position]) {
            return false;
        } elseif(!$GLOBALS['block_loop'][$loop_position][block_name] = $block_name) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $GLOBALS['loop_position'] = $loop_position+1;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This returns an infinite loop however and I can't figure out a way to move the while loop onto the next step?

**EDIT** I'm using a while loop because the function have_block will set-up a global variable for the current block id. This will then be used within a function called the_element. Such as:

```
if( loop_blocks()) {
    while( loop_blocks()) {
        if( have_block('standard-content-block')) {
            the_element('heading');
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't use the function have_block to set this up, then I'd need to pass the block id from the foreach loop into every element as a second argument.

Comment: why the heck do u need a while loop?

Comment: You could use a `foreach` loop to go through the full array. `foreach($res as $item) { //do things to item }`

Comment: Everytime you loop you reset `loop_position` to 0 in `loop_blocks()`. Please note though that Global variables are generally bad and in this case they are totally unecessary.

Comment: @Jim Thank-you, I had forgotten I had set that within loop_blocks().

Comment: check: "if(!$res) {" if query returns empty array it is still could be true but - logic I see - it must be false ;-) so i don't know what is your $db type is, just check what is result of fetchAll() when 0 records returns

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by, as @Jim, noted I was re-setting the loop_position within loop_blocks() which was why the while loop was repeating infinitely. It was then a simple case of an error when typing:

```
} elseif(!$GLOBALS['block_loop'][$loop_position][block_name] = $block_name) {
        return false;
```

Should have been:

```
} elseif($GLOBALS['block_loop'][$loop_position][block_name] != $block_name) {
        return false;
```

Note that I had the exclamation point in the incorrect place.
This now works perfectly as I need.

Comment: It wasn't necessarily that you had exclamation in the wrong place, you were using `=` as an assigment, instead of checking equality. It should have been `==` and you could have left the exclamation point at the beginning.